# Replace digits and non digits that are joined together - Redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace with a blank space the digits and non digits that are joined together immediately after the name of the medication:

Table:

```
molecule_name 
DOXICICLINA 100MG 
CAFEINA 50MG E DIPIRONA 300MG E CITRATO DE ORFENADRINA 35MG 
DIOSMINA 450MG E HESPERIDINA 50MG
```

Desired result:

```
new_molecule_name
DOXICICLINA 
CAFEINA E DIPIRONA E CITRATO DE ORFENADRINA 
DIOSMINA E HESPERIDINA
```

I tried to use the regex function to replace the digits with blank space:

`regexp_replace(molecule_name,'([0-9.])','') as new_molecule_name`

But the outcome still keeps the non-digits that are together with the digits:

```
DOXICICLINA MG
CAFEINA MG E DIPIRONA MG E CITRATO DE ORFENADRINA MG 
DIOSMINA MG E HESPERIDINA MG
```

How could I adjust this regex to capture and also replace only the non-digits that are associated with the numbers and keep the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regexp_replace(molecule_name,' [0-9]+[A-Z]*','') as new_molecule_name` will replace every number(at least 1 digit) immediately followed by any number of upper letters. If lower letters could appear use `[A-Za-z]*` instead.